# How to autosave file in Aptana Studio 3 before running?

Tags: python, aptana-studio

Using Aptana Studio 3 on my Windows 7 computer I'd like to have Aptana Studio 3 automatically save my Python file before running it.

Does someone know which checkbox (of those hundreds) I have to tick?

Answer (score 3):

for autosave:
go to Window > Preferences > in the left panel click Run/Debug > click Launching > Check Always button on the "Save required.."

to modify the shortcut key for Run:
in the left panel > General > Keys > search for Run > in Binding text box press F12(or whatever you want) > Apply